# Python parse list where data is not always present

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

Assuming the following python code where cast_value, directors_value, producers_value and screenwriters_value is not always filled with data:

```
def get_plist_names(name_dict):
    return [o["string"] for o in (name_dict if isinstance(name_dict, list) else [name_dict])]
```

...

```
plist_metadata = json.loads(dump_json)
dict = plist_metadata['plist']['dict']
zipped = zip(dict["key"], dict["array"])
result = {"cast": [], "directors": [], "screenwriters": [], "producers": [], } | \
                         {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
cast_value = (', '.join(result.get("cast", "")))
directors_value = (', '.join(result.get("directors", "")))
producers_value = (', '.join(result.get("producers", "")))
screenwriters_value = (', '.join(result.get("screenwriters", "")))
```

Why do I get the following error if for example ["cast"] has no data (at least I assume that the issue might be here):

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Is there any way that I can simply move on even if cast is empty?

Full trace:

```
celery           | [2021-06-16 15:04:50,761: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] Task Import Descriptor[6bd6c384-f800-4875-b78b-0e18a7a267e5] raised unexpected: TypeError('string indices must be integers')
celery           | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery           |   File "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
celery           |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
celery           |   File "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
celery           |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
celery           |   File "/app/Core/tasks.py", line 169, in import_descriptor
celery           |     {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
celery           |   File "/app/Core/tasks.py", line 169, in <dictcomp>
celery           |     {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
celery           | TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it maybe possible to use .get here?! and if so, how to do that?

Comment: Where exactly do you get that TypeError? The error means, that you try to use dictionary-like indexing by name `[""]` on a string, i.e., `"abc"["a"]` which only works with integers `"abc"[0]`. By the way, you should probably not overwrite builtin names like `dict`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with what you've given. `', '.join({"cast": []}["cast"])` does not raise an exception, it just returns an empty string. The error should point to the specific line where it happens, it would be helpful to show that.

Comment: As you can see with the error you just posted, it is complaining about `{k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}` not `cast`. It seems like `v` is a list not a dict. That makes some sense given it comes from a value named: `dict["array"]`.

Comment: Jep, that again really makes sense. Any Idea for a workaround?

Comment: A workaround would depend on specifically what you are  expecting `v["dict"]` and what `v` is. I don't think either of those is clear from the question.

Comment: Okay than I'll close this question the moment, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the error occurs in `cast_value` You could try using the `get` operator with an alternative empty string if empty.

```
cast_value = (', '.join(result.get("cast", "")))
```

I will note, however that the following returns an empty string rather than a type error so there may be an issue somewhere else in your code

```
result = {"cast": []}
','.join(result['cast'])
```

Output:

```
"" # empty string
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Using get should be a good practice anyway :)
Still as you mentioned the error happens at a different place. I added my trace to the question, maybe you have another hint.